# how to read a malformed wide csv in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I (quite surprisingly) have some difficulties to read a `csv` in Pandas with the following format (this is real stuff - believe me)

[image]

As you can see, the real data is:

- in a wide format
- only starts on row 6
- there is an empty column at B

I have tried the following, with no success.

```
my_df = pd.read_csv('P://mypath/bogus_csv.csv', 
                     skiprows = [0,1,2,3,4],
                     usecols = ([0]+ range(2,5)))
```

but that returns `ValueError: Passed header names mismatches usecols` and it not optimal at all because I have hardcoded the number of columns in usecol.

Indeed, I may not know in advance how many columns (dates) I have.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Edit: here is the `csv` as text (in sublime text):

```
Title   "text"
Metric  Parallel
Date Range  10 Jan 2018 - 11 Apr 2018
Content Web, Online, Fax

Label       "10 Jan 2018"   "11 Jan 2018"   "12 Jan 2018"   
"myquery"       70  108 92
```

Here is how it appears in wordpad

[image]

Comment: Well, read the file and then delete the 2nd column afterwards?

Comment: remove usecols, change to `skiprows=5`, and add a `dropna(axis=1, how='all')` call later

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @coldspeed does not work unfortunately

Comment: the date columns do not show up when doing that

Comment: Could you post your csv? As text, I mean.

Comment: done, thanks for helping!

Comment: one idea would be to use python to erase the first 4 rows of the file and the 2nd column before feeding to `read_csv`. How can I do that cleanly?

Comment: You're not going to be able to parse this csv without cleaning it, there is no clear separator

Comment: well manually deleting the bogus rows and deleting the second column fixes the problem. read_csv can read this file without problems. Fortunately there will alwasy be the same number of bogus rows and bogus columns

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex whitespace delimiter, and the 'csv' posted, you could try:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', delimiter=r"\s+", skiprows=5, header=None)
df = df.set_index(0)
df = df.T
df = df.set_index('Label')
```

With some transposing, and re-indexing, gives me:

```
0           myquery
Label              
10 Jan 2018      70
11 Jan 2018     108
12 Jan 2018      92
```

There is an annoying 0 hanging about in the Index label cell, but probably  won't get in the way

Another option is to use a simple whitespace delimiter, which gives offset NaNs, which we have to drop by column-wise splitting, followed by concatenation. Not so keen on this option.

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', delimiter=" ", skiprows=5, header=None)
df = df.set_index(0)
df = df.T
dfs = []
for col in df.columns:
    df_col = df[col]
    df_col = df_col.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
    dfs.append(df_col)
df = pd.concat(dfs, 1).sort_index(1).set_index('Label')
```

Comment: thanks! however I get `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 7, saw 4`

Comment: Trailing whitespace in the actual csv maybe? It worked for the sample csv data you posted.

Comment: Added another option, which uses a simple whitespace delimter. Might solve the problem of trailing whitespace?

Comment: that is very weird. I have added one more picture that shows the whitespaces. I am getting a similar tokenizing error as before. is the code working for you still?

Comment: anyway manually deleting the secold column and deleting the row 1 to 5 works. Can we do that in Python before loading to read_csv? that would be the working solution I guess

Comment: Added some random extra whitespace - still works for me. I also tried using `sep=" "` rather than `delimiter=" "`, and that also works fine. Tabs break it, as do whitespace before the first character of a line.