# how to delete a column from a csv?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `csv` file that, in a normal world, I would just open using

`pd.read_csv('path_to_my_csv.csv')`

Unfortunately, the csv is messed-up and I need to delete its second column before *feeding* it to Pandas.

How can I do that? This is not a duplicate of the other similar question because

- I do not know how many columns I have in total
- my column do not have names

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the name of the column?

Comment: nope, the column does not have a name. but its the second one for sure

Comment: If it's not a dupe of that then you'll need to be more specific with "messed-up"

Comment: just did. you could have waited just a few more minutes bro

Comment: Is that second column 'messed up' in such a way that pandas has difficulty in processing it?

Comment: Is there no header row? Or do you just not know the column names?

Comment: yes, let me show an example

Comment: Why do you need to drop the column *before* you get it into Pandas?

Comment: im going to close this one and update a previous related question. pisquare nailed it. that impossible processing is done yay

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775840/how-to-read-a-malformed-wide-csv-in-pandas

Comment: whatever lets keep this one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### [**`read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) `usecols`

`usecols` can take a callable

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, usecols=lambda c: c != 1)
```

Comment: lets keep this one